# Not able to connect my Codename One iOS app to my server

Tags: ios, codenameone

I was trying to build an iOS app using `Codename One`, I was successfully able to generate the build, but when installed on my device I'm not able to connect to my server. The app works fine on android and also there is no problem running it in the simulator.

After going through the code again I found out that the method `getResponseData()` in `class ConnectionRequest` was returning null. But I'm not able to understand why its not working only on iOS devices.

```
    Connection connection = null;
    Dialog progress = new InfiniteProgress().showInifiniteBlocking();
    try {
        connection = new Connection(data);
         NetworkManager networkManager = NetworkManager.getInstance();
         networkManager.addToQueueAndWait(connection);
         Log.p("Server timeout" + networkManager.getTimeout());
         networkManager.setTimeout(600000);
         if (connection.getResponseData() == null) {
             return null;
         }
      } finally {
         progress.dispose();
      }
```

Here connection is a class that extends `ConnectionRequest`

I'm a beginner and would be grateful if anyone could let me know the reason for the above mentioned issue, or if there is something wrong in the code.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your server address? iOS by default blocks non SSL secured server loads so you’ll need to look into disabling this if you don’t use https

Comment: Hi @BrandonStillitano. Thank you for the guidance. I'm using https, but still not able to connect to my server.

Comment: What's the actual URL? Does it have a valid HTTPS certificate? Is it accessible via the device browser? I suggest logging the response code etc. so you'll have information about what happened.

Comment: Thank you @ShaiAlmog for the reply. The actual url has a valid https certificate. It is accessible via the device's browser (Safari). I also did check the app log in the server, request sent over the browser is being responded but the requests from the app is not reaching the server.

Comment: What's the response code? Do you see something in the server logs? BTW you do notice that you set the timeout after the request was supposedly completed?

Comment: The request from the app is not reaching the server. I checked the log in the server and cannot find anything, I also tried the same on other iOS devices like on an iPhone 6 which also did not work out. But when I sent a request from httpBot, the request seems to reach the server and I can get the response.